# How to extract specific text from a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column, which I need to clean, because the data doesn't have the necessary format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'item': ["1","2","3","4","5","6"], 'store': ["a [note 3]","b  [note 98]","c ","a 
[note 222]","b","c"]})
print(df)

item         store
0    1    a [note 3]
1    2  b  [note 98]
2    3            c 
3    4  a [note 222]
4    5             b
5    6             c
```

The column, `'store'`, must be changed like this:

```
 item store
0    1     a
1    2     b
2    3     c
3    4     a
4    5     b
5    6     c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split by the opening square bracket and pick first index value in the resulting list.

```
df['store'] = df.store.str.split('\[').str[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regular expression.  Just split on the space and take the first character.

```
df['store'] = df['store'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0])
```

If you end up needing regex, you can use extract

```
df['store'] = df['store'].str.extract('^([a-z])')
```

If you have multiple characters before the bracket

```
df['store'] = df['store'].str.extract('^(.+?)(?=\[|$)')
```

Comment: Note, using the `.str` accessor with `.split`, as shown by [wwnde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8986975/wwnde), is vectorized, and will be much faster than using `.apply`.

Comment: I have a question, in my example i didnt consider this kinda character: "Aa A [note 3]". Trying the solution with "str.extract", it turns NAN. How can i fixed it?

Comment: added another example if you want to try it